# Rest Assured - Is it possible to POST inside a test and then GET the response?

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

I’m trying to test some endpoints, but putting the url in a constant makes the tests brittle, as in, if some id no longer exists in the db, the test will return a 404 rather than the expected 200. Is it possible to post inside a test to ensure the entry exists before calling the GET?

Comment: Have you tried doing it?

Comment: I guess I’m confused how the post would look. I have the gets set up in a given(), when(), then() format. I’ve tried putting the post in the given before and after the when with no luck. Should it be outside completely?

Answer (score 0):

Either setup a pretest routine to add a test record to the database and a post test routine to delete it again, or add it in the test, do your test, and delete it.

Comment: How would that look? I’ve tried to add the post inside the test but I must be doing something syntactically wrong. Would the post be apart of the given()?

Comment: At a quick glance you could look at something like this https://techbeacon.com/app-dev-testing/how-perform-api-testing-rest-assured.